# SOLR: Rank high certain documents based on field value

Tags: solr, lucene

SOLR 4.2.1

How to rank certain documents with higher score based on a field value that they will be on the top of search results?

I am posting XML documents to SOLR and based on a field value, I am trying to rank them with higher values that those documents will come first on the search result. I tried using sort on that field, but it affects other sorting conditions that I have on the search query.

For ex:

```
<doc>
    <name>Joe</name>
    <code>Alpha</code>
    ...
</doc>
<doc>
    <name>Joe A</name>
    <code>AlphaX</code>
    ...
</doc>
<doc>
    <name>Joe B</name>
    <code>AlphaX</code>
    ...
</doc>
<doc>
    <name>Joe C</name>
    <code>AlphaY</code>
    ...
</doc>
<doc>
    <name>Joe D</name>
    <code>AlphaZ</code>
    ...
</doc>
```

In this, when I search for *Joe* or *Alpha*, I want the results like *Joe C, Joe A, Joe B, Joe, Joe d*
Any help is much appreciated.

**Update:** I tried the boost attribute on the doc and I couldn't get that work. But boosting the field worked only when I search on that particular field value. But if I searched for other field, its not.

Thank you.

Comment: See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_change_the_score_of_a_document_based_on_the_.2Avalue.2A_of_a_field_.28say.2C_.22popularity.22.29